# Let A be a 2×2 matrix, y an invariant line of A, and P a point on y. Is P necessarily an eigenvector of A?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let **A** be a 2×2 matrix, *y* an invariant line of **A**, and  P a point on *y*.

Is P necessarily an eigenvector of **A**?

If so then must it follow that any point on *y* is also an eigenvector of **A**, corresponding to a unique eigenvalue λ?  If all of the above is true, how do I show the uniqueness of λ?

*PS:

My textbook seems to be implying the above is all true, but I'm not given much detail as to why.

(For reference, I'm familiar with the basic definitions of all the items I mentioned, and (linear) eigenvector equations.) Thanks.*

Comment: Is it a line through the origin? If so then it is not very hard to see that all nonzero vectors on an invariant line are eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue. Just play around with the definition of linearity a bit.

Comment: You're right.  I was confusing myself unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. $Av=\lambda v$, then any $w=\mu v$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Proof: $Aw = A\mu v = \mu A v = \mu \lambda v = \lambda \mu v = \lambda w.$

Answer (score 0):

You have $U=\mathrm{span} \{p\}$. Since $U$ is invariant under $A$, there is some $\mu$ s.t. $Ap=\mu p$. Therefore $\mu$ is the eigenvalue of $p$ and for $p'=\lambda p\in U$ you have $Ap'=\lambda Ap=\lambda \mu p = \mu p'$, therefore $\mu$ is eigenvalue of $p'$ as well.

Eigenvalues are always unique: $\lambda \neq \mu$ eigenvalue of $p$, then $\lambda p = Ap=\mu p$ implies $\lambda-\mu=0$, contradiction.